# changing sitecore website default URL structure

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, sitecore, sitecore-sxa

I have a sitecore website with a default URL structure http:/ /www.domain.com/language/country/abc/xxx/........ due to SEO friendly we need to have language after country,Any idea if I can reset the format to something else,like http: //www. domain.com/country/language/abc/xxx/......?
can this be done on iis rewrite,if yes how.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you specify your language and country so That I can match them in parameters.

Here is a sample for your reference：

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
     <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$" />
   </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://[www.domain.com]/{C:2}/{C:1}/{C:3}" />
</rule>
```